# Image Sprite wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Similar to using a sprite image in HTML/CSS, I would like to create this with WP7. I have tries using:

```
   <Grid.Resources>
     <ImageBrush x:Key="Test"  ImageSource="/Resources/Images/thumbnails.png"
          AlignmentX="0" AlignmentY="0" Stretch="Fill"/>
   </Grid.Resources>

<Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="{StaticResource Test}" Width="22" Height="18" />
```

Not sure how to set up if the first image in the sprite start at 0,0, and is 22 width, by 18 height?

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this is by adding creating a Canvas and assigning a rectangular geometry to the Clip property of the Canvas.

This Canvas will be the sprite control. Next add to the Canvas the Image you want to display and position the image so the correct part of the bitmap is shown and the rest is cut off by the clip (I didn't test the code there might be tiny errors):

```
<Canvas Width="[Width of the sprite frame]" Height="[width of the sprite frame]">
    <Canvas.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry 
             Rect="0,0,[width-of-the-Canvas],[height-of-the-Canvas]" />
    </Canvas.Clip>
    <Image Source="[uri]" Canvas.Left="[x-offset]" Canvas.Top="[y-offset]" />
</Canvas>
```

If you're feeling adventurous you could bind the size of the Rect to the size of the Canvas...